# Golang hot reloading not working on docker with CompileDaemon in dev mode

Tags: docker, go

I wanna make hot reloading for Golang on docker. I have created a Docker file looks like this:

```
# Go Version
FROM golang:latest

# Environment variables which CompileDaemon requires to run
ENV PROJECT_DIR=/app \
    GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0

# Basic setup of the container
RUN mkdir /app
COPY .. /app
WORKDIR /app

# Get CompileDaemon
RUN go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
RUN go install github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon

# The build flag sets how to build after a change has been detected in the source code
# The command flag sets how to run the app after it has been built
ENTRYPOINT CompileDaemon -build="go build -o api" -command="./api"
```

**and docker-compose.yml is:**

```
version: '3.8'

name: live-reload-example

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 8501:8501
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

The container not reloading after the change

Comment: It is always good to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, what does the log say?

Answer (score 0):

Container should not be reloaded. It runs `CompilerDaemon`. The daemon watches the mounted files and recompiles+restarts the app upon change.

I'm not sure about `COPY .. /app` - what's there in `..`? I replaced it with `COPY . /app` and it worked with my duppy app.

Just a few points:

- No need to create `/app`, `WORKDIR` creates it automatically,
- No need to copy your app to `/app` upon build since `go build` is invoked after start, and the contents of `/app` is overloaded by the mounted volume

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest

# Environment variables which CompileDaemon requires to run
ENV PROJECT_DIR=/app \
    GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0

# Basic setup of the container
WORKDIR /app
# dummy module to make `go get` happy
RUN go mod init dummy

# Get CompileDaemon
RUN go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
RUN go install github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon

# The build flag sets how to build after a change has been detected in the source code
# The command flag sets how to run the app after it has been built
ENTRYPOINT CompileDaemon -build="go build -o api" -command="./api"
```

Here is the log of `docker compose up`:

```
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:24 Running build command!
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:24 Build ok.
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:24 Restarting the given command.
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:24 stdout: Hello, world! Version 1
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 Running build command!
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 Build ok.
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 Hard stopping the current process..
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 Restarting the given command.
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 stdout: Hello, world! Version 2
```

As you see, when the container started, it built my application and launched it. The output of the application:

```
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:24 stdout: Hello, world! Version 1
```

Then I edited the app and changed the line to `Version 2`:

```
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 Running build command!
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 Build ok.
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 Hard stopping the current process..
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 Restarting the given command.
api  | 2024/02/10 17:52:35 stdout: Hello, world! Version 2
```

IMHO, the container works as expected: it watches changes in sources and rebuilds and restarts the application.

Comment: I think your answer is true. However, the problem has not been solved on my device. some people said the problem may be related to the Docker engine system, although I used air package instead of CompileDaemon

Answer (score 0):

I used air package instead of CompileDaemon and problem solved.

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /go-app


COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

# Install the air binary so we get live code-reloading when we save files
RUN curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin


CMD ["air", "-c", ".air.toml"]
```

in the first step, the .air.toml file does not exist, and you must create it with air init in the docker container.